# Tomcat SSL Configuration on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, tomcat, https

I have been struggling for days and decided to come here and ask the experts for assistance. I currently have an Ubuntu 18.04 fresh installation that I am trying to get Tomcat 9.0.30 to run on over SSL.

My installation procedure thus far was following this URL mostly and then adding the required SSL config:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I can get the Tomcat pages to show up no problem with normal HTTP and I can access and manage the Tomcat instance without problems. The only problem is making the HTTPS connectivity work. My current server.xml file is configured (except for the default values) as follows;

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="9443" />

    <Connector  port="9443"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                maxThreads="150"
                SSLEnabled="true"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                clientAuth="false"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                keystoreFile="/etc/online-intelligence/ssl-certs/ssl.pfx"
                keystoreType="PKCS12"
                keystorePass="password" />
```

Now, as I said, with this configuration I can access and manage the instance over an HTTP connection, but the HTTPS connection is down entirely. See below extract from the Catalina.out file after starting the instance;

```
02-Jan-2020 14:53:02.546 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
02-Jan-2020 14:53:02.563 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9443"]
02-Jan-2020 14:53:02.716 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9443$
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1057)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:303)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Detect premature EOF
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:217)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1154)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:575)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Detect premature EOF
                at java.base/sun.security.util.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:69)
                at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:411)
                at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:331)
                at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:344)
                at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1993)
                at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
```

I have searched for this error message endlessly and I am sure it's something stupid I am missing but for the life of me I cannot figure it out...

Can anyone provide me with assistance please? Let me know if I can / should post more details?

Comment: Can your process access certificate stored in /etc/online-intelligence/ssl-certs/ ? To verify you may create dummy keystore inside home folder or use SSLCertificateFile. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html.

Comment: Hi yes, just to make sure I ran 'sudo chmod -R a+rwx /etc/online-intelligence/ssl-certs' and then restarted Tomcat. Same issue in the logs persists